Jenkinsfile Interpolation Syntax Issue
I have the following Step in my Declarative Jenkinsfile:
stage('Download Lambda Artifacts') {
    steps {
        script {
            withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: ARTIFACTORY_CREDENTIALS_ID, usernameVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD')]) {
                def lambdaNames = env.LAMBDA_NAME.tokenize(',')
                for (lambdaName in lambdaNames) {
                    sh '''
                        python get-artifact.py -u ${ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME} -p ${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD} -b "${lambdaName}.jar"
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The python script essentially just downloads the ${lambdaName}.jar from my Artifactory, and LAMBDA_NAME is just a bunch of strings separated by a comma.
Here is my issue: "${lambdaName}.jar" is not being interpolated, and is an empty value.
If i use """ for my sh instead of ''', it works, but then I get the warning about my ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME/PASSWORD having insecure interpolation of sensitive variables.
I'm sure it's a simple syntax issue, and I though wrapping my ${lambdaName} within "" would fix the issue. Is anyone able to see an solution? Many thanks.

As you seem to already know from the question, you need to interpolate the lambdaName as a Groovy variable within the string, and resolve the credentials variables as environment variables in the shell interpreter to avoid leaking them in the pipeline logs. You can achieve this via:
sh "python get-artifact.py -u \${ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME} -p \${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD} -b ${lambdaName}.jar"

Escaping the $ characters prevents Groovy from interpolating them within the string, and will instead cause them to be resolved by the shell interpreter. The " syntax interpolates the lambdaName as per usual within the Groovy string as you expect.

Thank you for the detailed response. Very interestingly, I've changed to sh """ and escaped my ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME/PASSWORD env vars. My Jenkins pipeline still throws the insecure interpolation of sensitive variables warning, but for ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME only. Before it was for both:
sh """  python get-artifact.py -u \${ARTIFACTORY_USERNAME} -p \${ARTIFACTORY_PASSWORD} ${lambdaName},jar """

@Josh You accidentally used """ syntax for a single-line string instead of my answer, but functionally it is equivalent so pipeline is probably warning a false positive. Anyway, glad I was able to answer your question.

My stage here is a multi-line set of commands, i just removed them for simplicity when asking this question, and the fact they don't use the lambdaName Groovy variable. Yeah, I'm much more comfortable with a Username being "insecure" than a password :). Thanks again.
